# org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'

Tags: glassfish, spring-ws

I've built a simple Spring WS (1.5.9) and I'm trying to deploy it to Glassfish v3. Unfortunately the deployment fails for the above reason. I've struggled to resolve the issue myself but it clearly not able to resolve the "bean" element.

Heres me `spring-ws-servlet.xml` (bean definitions):

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

...bean definitions

</beans>
```

I've also tried it with the `schemaLocation` set to `spring-beans-3.0.xsd` with the same result.

My WAR only has one dependency and that is Spring-WS.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided the standard collection of schema locations, particularly not the required schema location for the beans schema.

Here's one of mine:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xmlns:gate="http://gate.ac.uk/ns/spring"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://gate.ac.uk/ns/spring http://gate.ac.uk/ns/spring.xsd
    ">
</beans>
```

Comment: Cheers buddy - I think thats fixed that particular issue. schemaLocation has two parts - namespace and file - and I only had file.

Answer (score 0):

The same fail was happened to me when I copied the beans tag from another file on internet, you have to secure that you've typped a space between the html sentences.

```
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"(space)xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"(space)
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"(space)   
      ....
     ">
        </beans>
```